# Call a function on a checkbox

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm a beginner on React. And I would like to call a function on a checkbox.

Here is my code :

```js
<div>
    <img src={user.picture} alt={user.name}/>
    <h2> {user.name} </h2>
    <WeatherFront></WeatherFront> 
</div>
```

But I would like to do something like that :

```js
<div>
  <img src={user.picture} alt={user.name}/>
  <h2> {user.name} </h2>
  <Stack tokens={stackTokens}>
      <Checkbox label="Weather" onChange={_onChangeWeather} />
  </Stack>
</div>
```

call function when checkbox changed:

```js
function _onChangeWeather(ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>, isChecked: boolean) {
    <WeatherFront></WeatherFront> 
}
```

But it doesn't works.... Someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: i think, you want to show/hide `WeatherFront` component based on checkbox toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

function _onChangeWeather() {
  setIsChecked(!isChecked);
}

return (
  <div>
    <img src={user.picture} alt={user.name} />
    <h2> {user.name} </h2>
    <Stack tokens={stackTokens}>
      <Checkbox label="Weather" onChange={_onChangeWeather} />
    </Stack>
    {isChecked ? <Weather /> : ''}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: It can show me my widget if I click on the checkbox. But how can I do if I want hide it ?